# Updating Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I am having trouble updating from Drupal 8.3.7

when running "composer why-not drupal/core 8.4.0" i get the following results:

drupal/core                 8.4.0       requires          symfony/class-loader (~3.2.8)
andeersg/bouvet-d8-project  dev-Stinis  does not require  symfony/class-loader (but v2.8.28 is installed)
drupal/core                 8.4.0       requires          symfony/console (~3.2.8)
andeersg/bouvet-d8-project  dev-Stinis  does not require  symfony/console (but v2.8.28 is installed)
drupal/core                 8.4.0       requires          symfony/dependency-injection (~3.2.8)
andeersg/bouvet-d8-project  dev-Stinis  does not require  symfony/dependency-injection (but v2.8.28 is installed)
drupal/core                 8.4.0       requires          symfony/event-dispatcher (~3.2.8)
andeersg/bouvet-d8-project  dev-Stinis  does not require  symfony/event-dispatcher (but v2.8.28 is installed)
drupal/core                 8.4.0       requires          symfony/http-foundation (~3.2.8)
andeersg/bouvet-d8-project  dev-Stinis  does not require  symfony/http-foundation (but v2.8.28 is installed)
drupal/core                 8.4.0       requires          symfony/http-kernel (~3.2.8)
andeersg/bouvet-d8-project  dev-Stinis  does not require  symfony/http-kernel (but v2.8.28 is installed)
drupal/core                 8.4.0       requires          symfony/process (~3.2.8)
andeersg/bouvet-d8-project  dev-Stinis  does not require  symfony/process (but v2.8.28 is installed)
drupal/core                 8.4.0       requires          symfony/routing (~3.2.8)
andeersg/bouvet-d8-project  dev-Stinis  does not require  symfony/routing (but v2.8.28 is installed)
drupal/core                 8.4.0       requires          symfony/serializer (~3.2.8)
andeersg/bouvet-d8-project  dev-Stinis  does not require  symfony/serializer (but v2.8.28 is installed)
drupal/core                 8.4.0       requires          symfony/translation (~3.2.8)
andeersg/bouvet-d8-project  dev-Stinis  does not require  symfony/translation (but v2.8.28 is installed)
drupal/core                 8.4.0       requires          symfony/validator (~3.2.8)
andeersg/bouvet-d8-project  dev-Stinis  does not require  symfony/validator (but v2.8.28 is installed)
drupal/core                 8.4.0       requires          symfony/yaml (~3.2.8)
andeersg/bouvet-d8-project  dev-Stinis  does not require  symfony/yaml (but v2.8.28 is installed)

Trying to update one of the mentioned packages just result in composer telling me i cant because Drupal 8.3.7 needs a lower version. So i cant update the packages and i cant update Drupal, am i stuck in a catch22?

Does anybody know what the problem might be?

Comment: You can use Drush, its very easy to update your core version than using composer

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a drush or composer expert, so I can't tell u what is causing the problem. But personally, I update Drupal core manually every time and it's a very easy task. All you need to do is to follow these steps :

1. Download the latest Drupal 8 core version from this address: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal
2. Make a copy of the following 4 folders in your existing Drupal root: modules, themes, profiles, sites ( if you have made changes to your .htaccess file, make a copy of that too )
3. Extract the contents of new Drupal zip file on your website root and let them replace the old files.
4. Paste the 4 folders mentioned above back to the website root and let them replace new folders.

That's all! You've successfully updated your Drupal core. Don't forget to make the database update after logging in to a website if needed.

Hope this helps someone.